select users with same SSN and MAX process date DB2
I need to find all the users who have a MAX Process date. There are often multiple records for the same person but different process dates.
PROCESS_DATE | SSN         | Amount  | CODE | SOURCE | TRADE_DATE | SHARECOST
11/12/2024   | 00-47-0004  | 111.11  | 1    |  1     | 12/10/2024 | 20.07
11/11/2024   | 00-47-0004  | 22.2    | 2    |  2     | 10/10/2024 | 20.07
11/12/2024   | 00-47-0004  | 0.00    | 13   |  1     | 11/10/2024 | 20.07
11/10/2024   | 00-45-0042  | 0.00    | 2    |  1     | 12/10/2024 | 20.07
11/09/2024   | 00-45-0012  | 7.77    | 5    |  2     | 12/10/2024 | 20.07

I am using a subquery with max process date, fetching row_number() over SSN and process date, and picking the first row.
I expected
PROCESS_DATE | SSN         | Amount  | CODE | SOURCE | TRADE_DATE | SHARECOST
11/12/2024   | 00-47-0004  | 111.11  | 1    |1       |12/10/2024  | 20.07
11/10/2024   | 00-45-0042  | 0.00    | 2    |1       |12/10/2024  | 20.07

but this query fails when the record count is over a million.
SELECT SSN,
       PROCESS_DATE,
       AMOUNT,
       CODE, SOURCE, TRADE_DATE, SHARECOST
FROM ( SELECT SSN,
              PROCESS_DATE,
              AMOUNT,
              CODE, SOURCE, TRADE_DATE, SHARECOST
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION SSN ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE) AS RN
       FROM TABLE 
      ) AS RANK 
WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY SSN;

It takes a long time to execute and fails with

resource error SQL ERROR 57011 Unsucesfull execution cause by an
unavailable resource, reason 00C90305

How do I optimize the query?

It takes long to execute and fails with resource error SQL ERROR 57011 Unsucesfull execution cause by an unavailable resource, reason 00C90305

Expected resul should include ('11/09/2024',   '00-45-0012'  , 7.77    , 5) ?

You have to do ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE DESC to get the max date row.

Which row do you want for a user who has several rows with its max date?

I have a table with fields plan,ssn, trade date ,fund ,source, item, share, cash, cost, and process date. When I run the subquery, it still fetches duplicate ssn since there are unique values in other fields, any suggestion how I can filter to fetch just the top 1 row after max of process date. This is in DB 2 and when I try FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY I get error column or EXPRESSION IN the SELECT LIST is not valid for other fields

What's the primary key of the table?

There is no primary key, this is the history data of shares so all fields can be duplicates.

please update the question with details on what exactly you mean by 1st row and top 1 row; are we to pick any row or do we need to pick the 'one' row based on an ordering of other columns? for example, in your expected output it looks like you want 1st row / top 1 row to be the row with min(code)

I updated the Question,  I need to fetch the TOP 1 record per ssn with max process data after filtering. The query I am using works fine for the smaller data set and once the data set is large ~1mil it throws a resource error.

you're missing the point, 1st row and top 1 row have no meaning by themselves unless you can explicitly tell us that we can pick any 1st row / top 1 row in which case you're not (technically) guaranteed to obtain the same result with repeated runs of the query; if you expect the same result for each run of the query then we need to know how you're prioritizing/sorting a subset of rows that have the same ssn + process_date in order to come up with the same 1st row / top 1 row each time the query is run

I am new to Mainframes and trying to fetch data from main frame to generate a report. I need to Sort by SSN DESC with MAX(PROCESS_DATE), the expectation is this will fetch a GROUP of SSN with MAX(PROCESS_DATE) and I pick the first row from this subset.

what do you mean by I pick the first row? the question we keep asking you is HOW are you picking that first row? are you picking ANY row at random? are you ordering the data by some other column(s) and then picking the first row? generally speaking a relational database does not guarantee the ordering of the data you are presented with unless you provide some means of filtering and ordering the data; if you require the same result on repeated runs of the query then first row must be accompanied by a description of how to determine WHICH row should be considered first

you've stated in various comments ... you have 1+ million rows of data ... you can't add ddl (eg, indexes) to the legacy/mainframe database ... you want to write queries that have different filtering conditions (above and beyond what was listed in your original question); unless your data contains a lot of (var)binary/LOB/RAW data, 1+ million rows can't be that much data in which case maybe you should look at downloading this set of data into a local (modern) database where you can add indices and have (better) support for (SQL) windowing functions

Reason code 00C90305 means you exceeded the MAXTEMPS limit. Ask your admin to enlarge it.

You are dragging your entire table into Temp space before working on it.  Instead, do a subquery to get max date by SSN, then use it to filter your table.
Select mytable.*
From mytable inner join
  (Select SSN, max(Process_Date) as last
    From mytable
    Group by SSN) filter
  On mytable.SSN=filter.SSN and
     mytable.Process_Date=filter.last

This may still fail if you have millions of people with relatively few interactions. But I suspect the subquery will  boil down to a smaller size that will fit your Temp space.

Thanks, Chris for the response, I have a table with fields plan,ssn, trade date ,fund ,source, item, share, cash, cost, and process date. When I run the subquery, it still fetches duplicate ssn since there are unique values in other fields, any suggestion how I can filter to fetch just the top 1 row after max of process date

If you have several rows for process_date, you should define unambiguous order for top 1 row.

Try also
select *
from myTable t1
where t1.process_date=(
    select process_date from myTable t2 
    where t2.ssn=t1.ssn 
    order by process_date desc
    fetch first 1 row only
    ) 

I think, for query perfomance index on(ssn,process_date)  is very usefull.

Do order by process_date desc to get the max date.

@jarlh, yes, corrected. Thank you.

This will not work since the Amount and code also have unique values. WHen running this in DB2 gives the error COLUMN or expression in the select list is not valid.

This is an uninteresting error.

Assumptions/Understandings:

based on OP's expected output I'm guessing 1st row / top 1 row refers to the row with the smallest code, ie, min(code)
we need to stay away from windowing functions due to a resource issue in OP's environment
OP's sample input shows 3 distinct ssn values but the expected output only shows two of the ssn values; at this point I'm guessing a) there's a typo in the inputs or b) OP accidentally left out a row in the expected output

Adding a row to OP's sample input:
insert TABLE_X values ('11/12/2024','00-47-0004',111.11,1)
insert TABLE_X values ('11/11/2024','00-47-0004', 22.20,2)
insert TABLE_X values ('11/12/2024','00-47-0004',  0.00,13)

insert TABLE_X values ('11/10/2024','00-45-0042',  0.00,2)
insert TABLE_X values ('11/01/2024','00-45-0042', 23.19,7)

insert TABLE_X values ('11/09/2024','00-45-0012',  7.77,5)

One idea:
select  t1.PROCESS_DATE,
        t1.SSN,
        t1.AMOUNT,
        t1.CODE

from    TABLE_X t1

join    (select t2.SSN,
                max(t2.PROCESS_DATE) max_date
         from   TABLE_X t2
         group by t2.SSN) as dt

on      t1.SSN          = dt.SSN
and     t1.PROCESS_DATE = dt.max_date

where   t1.CODE = (select       min(t3.CODE)
                     from       TABLE_X t3
                     where      t3.SSN          = dt.SSN
                     and        t3.PROCESS_DATE = dt.max_date)

order by t1.SSN desc

This generates:
 PROCESS_DATE SSN        AMOUNT CODE 
 ------------ ---------- ------ ---- 
 11/12/2024   00-47-0004 111.11    1 
 11/10/2024   00-45-0042   0.00    2 
 11/09/2024   00-45-0012   7.77    5

NOTES:

I added the order by to insure I generate the output in the same order as OP's expected output
I'm assuming OP's table has an index to support this query, eg,  (SSN, PROCESS_DATE [, CODE])
I don't have access to a DB2 database so I tested this in a Sybase ASE instance; this is fairly basic SQL so I'm guessing/hoping this should be free of syntax issues
in my test database I used datetime and money datatypes; I've a) left out some reformatting code and b) took the liberty of adjusting the spacing in the final output in order to get this to look like OP's output


Thanks, Mark, this helps. I am new to this working with a legacy DB2 SAS-based application migrating to newer apps. Do I have to write multiple where clauses if I need to filter more fields, which I tried but failed to fetch correct data like for the below fields
SSN,PLAN,Processdate,amount,code,source,share,cost,txndate
I tried max - process date then in where max amount, max code, max source which filtered more results than existing, since this is a legacy system, it hard to change anything on mainframes to add indexes.

before you go changing the requirements (ie, modifying the question, adding requirements in comments) you need to tell us if our answers address your original requirement; does this query generate the desired results (one row per unique ssn+process_date) for your sample set of 5 rows? does this query generate the correct result (one row per unique ssn+process_date) for your million+ row data set? assuming the answers are 'yes' then that would imply this Q&A is done and you can upvote/downvote/accept answers as you see fit ...

if you then have problems modifying these (correct, working) answers with additional requirements then you should ask a new question, making sure to provide all necessary details and your modified query(s); it's frowned upon to modify a stackoverflow question if said changes have the effect of negating the answers that you've already received
